# Directory of GS_LOG environment variable does not exist

Tags: linux, nodes, griddb

I am having trouble while starting `cluster` nodes on `GridDB` gsadm. Using the command in `Ubuntu` I was starting a node, but now I am getting an error as follows

> Directory of GS_LOG environment variable does not exist.

The command I was using to start the node can be seen in the following screenshot
[image: screenshot]

I have followed the given [documentation](https://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/en/pro/griddb/docs-en/v4_5/GridDB_QuickStartGuide.html#starting-a-node)

To start the node on `GridDB` gsadm using the username and password.I have already set the `GS_HOME` and `GS_LOG` right after installing the GridDB, but it's not working while starting a node.